# How can I obtain inverse Laplace transformation of the following complementary error function

Tags: inverse-laplace

I have obtained this expression in a solution (in Laplace time domain). I wonder if it can be inverse transformed to real-time domain without using numerical methods.

$$ erfc(a+b\sqrt{ z})\exp(c\sqrt{ z})$$